# Mp4 video not working in IE11

Tags: html, video

i have a video tag , even though the codec is given in IE11 video format is not supported error is occuring.

is there any other codec that should be given for mp4.

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" poster="snapshot.png" preload="none" controls=""><source src="newVideo.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs=\"avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2\"'></video>
```

Comment: did you get any errors?

Comment: does it work if you don't specify the codec? also, is there any reason to escape the double quote (as you're surrounding the type with single quote)? Also, is IE11 dropping back to IE9 compatibility mode because of anything else on the page (force it with `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> `)

Comment: yes error is Unsupported video type or invalid file path

Comment: i made the content to show in IE10 like content ="IE=10", i have issue with IE 11 in  IE edge its working fine

Comment: i have given without codecs but to work in IE11 i given this codec but its not working

Comment: can you try this `<source src="movie.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"'>`

Comment: will check so the change is avc1.42E01E => avc1.4D401E

Comment: tried didnt worked in IE11

Comment: @AravindS it didnt worked

Comment: Instead of your original video, can try with some other video and see whether its working in IE11

Comment: I reset the IE settings it was fixed. Thanks for the support Aravind